# What is this cryptic switch case code in swift means?

Tags: swift

I'm tasked to continue development of a swift iOS app where the previous developer can't be contacted again. I stumble upon a strange switch code case that I never see before. This is the code from Swift 2 syntax.

```
switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
    case (1, let row):
        row
        self.doSomethingIrrelevantWithRow();
        return;
    default: break
}
```

I just wonder, what does `case (1, let row):` means? I mean, I never even know that I can have a `let` inside of a case. Can somebody explain why and how we can use `let` inside a case correctly? Thanks.

Comment: It's called value binding, which is covered in the [Control Flow](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) section of the Swift Language Guide

Comment: It's called [pattern matching](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html). [Here](https://appventure.me/2015/08/20/swift-pattern-matching-in-detail/) is a nice explanation.

Comment: Directly from the Swift Language Reference: *"... `case (let x, 0)` matches any point with a `y` value of `0` and assigns the point’s `x` value to the temporary constant `x`."*

Comment: @TomKnapen oh wow, the explanation is really mind opening. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinR thanks. your comment is actually the most relevant answer to the question.

Comment: @Keiwan I have read that, but usually I learn the most by stumbling upon something. When I read a full length page of explanation like that, my brain just unconsciously filter everything as not important, thus can't retain it into memory lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift documentation cover this part perfectly.

> A switch case can bind the value or values it matches to temporary
>   constants or variables, for use in the body of the case. This behavior
>   is known as value binding, because the values are bound to temporary
>   constants or variables within the case’s body.